# All mean values plotted in all charts, only want each specific mean value for each chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Working on plotting values and their means, for two distributions. The data:

```
x1 <- c(0.6800000, 0.6634863, 0.6534353, 0.6596089, 0.6636000)
x2 <- c(0.6866667, 0.6973262, 0.6894212, 0.6892579, 0.6829512)
x1_mean <- mean(x1)
x2_mean <- mean(x2)
```

Make this into a simple data set:

```
test01 <- data.frame('count' = 1:5, 'model' = c(rep('x1',5), rep('x2', 5)), 'accuracy' = c(x1, x2), 'mean' = c(x1_mean, x2_mean))
```

Now plot the values, and the means. Separate by model, but the mean line for both sets of data show up on both plots. How can the mean line show up only on its own chart?

```
ggplot(test01, aes(x = count, y = accuracy, color = model)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = count, y = accuracy)) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = count, y = accuracy)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean)) +
  facet_grid(~model)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I changed `mean` to `Mean` just for good practice to avoid conflict with `mean()`

Looking at `test01` reveals why there are two lines on each facet. How the `data.frame()` recycled the `Mean` object made it so the that there are different means on each plot even after the facetting. So just fix `test01` so that the `Mean` is constant per `model`.

```
test01 <- data.frame('count' = 1:5, 'model' = c(rep('x1',5), rep('x2', 5)), 'accuracy' = c(x1, x2), 'Mean' =rep( c(x1_mean, x2_mean),each=5))
```

[image]